# Elapsed time of the query is abnormal in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to find the elapsed time of the query in SQLSERVER using the view, sys.dm_exec_requests. For some queries the elapsed time is more than an hour, most of the queries coming up when using sys.dm_exec_requests are parameterized queries. I want to know if there is any known behavior of this sort and what can I do to correct this issue.

Comment: `sys.dm_exec_requests` is for currently active executions, if the elapsed time is more than an hour then you'll need to figure out why. I don't see any issues or bugs here.

Comment: You may find it easier to use a pre-made solution for doing this, like [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/).

Comment: ...In other words, there are queries running on your server for over an hour.